# undocking and redocking Thinkpad T460s make logitech mouse stop working

Tags: windows-7, laptop, mouse, thinkpad

I'm having a very specific problem with my Thinkpad T460s and my Logitech gaming mouse (I forget the exact model).

I have a docking station.  When I plug the laptop into the docking station and turn it on, everything is fine.  But if I undock and redock the laptop, the Logitech gaming software fails to detect my mouse, which makes the mouse default to its hardware configuration.  I used to be able to solve this by restarting the gaming software, but now that no longer works, and if I unplug either the mouse or my keyboard then plug them back in, the laptop never detects them.  This happens even when I plug them directly into the laptop, rather than the docking station.  The only way to solve this is to reboot.